# How to remove title of a HTML page which will loaded in a Android WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am using webview in my android app. I am using ActionBar to show the title. So I want to remove title of HTML page shown in webview.  So how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my HTML page having tag as:

```
<div class="titlebar">Terms and Conditions</div>
```

So, following code has solved my problem using `getElementsByClassName`:

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('titlebar')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " +
                    "})()");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

        web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('pagelet_bluebar')[0].style.display=\"none\";");

    }
})
```

Or go for [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download)

Comment: No error is there but the title is still visible in WebView.